# How to create BST in post order-way - algorithm theory

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm preparing to exam from algorithms and have exercise which I do not understand:
"Create a BST from given numbers and write it by post-order method. Choose correct order in this notation."

Numbers: 42, 30, 45, 55, 70, 53, 40, 33, 60, 50

Anserws:

[image: anserws]

So I've started to think about this excercise and decided to sketch BST graph like this:
[image: graph]

And I was thought that if I will read numbers from graph in post-order way, I will receive answer, but no. I think BST tree is ok, maybe I should create BST already in post-order notation somehow?

Comment: Your initial interpretation of the problem is correct. You have a list of numbers to be inserted into a BST, from left to right, then would like to walk the tree via post order traversal. However, your BST isn't quite correct. Since it is multiple choice question though you could just solve it really quickly if you're aware that the root of a binary tree is the last element in the post order traversal.

Comment: Remember that BSTs have a strict order: everything to the left of a node is smaller, and everything to its right is bigger.

Comment: Maybe you'd notice your mistake if you wrote the numbers legibly?

Comment: If time runs out during the exam, pick "a" because it's the only one that ends with 42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake in drawing the BST. The regulations for making a BST is,

> the left-subtree's value for each node, should always be lesser than the current root.
>
> the right-subtree's value for each node, should always be greater than the current root.

Now consider the sub-tree, that you have drew:

```
           45  
      55          70
 53       60
```

It's not following BST's property, re-draw the diagram, and try for Post-Order as demanded.

The property of Post-order is following:

```
     1. visit left sub-tree.
     2. visit right sub-tree.
     3. visit the root.
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think BST tree is ok,

You made a mistake in drawing the BST when you inserted 53. It should not become the left child of 45, but its right child. It was the only mistake, but it obviously had big consequences for the rest of the values that you inserted in the BST.

> I was thought that if I will read numbers from graph in post-order way, I will receive answer

That is right. If you recreate the BST without mistakes, this is the correct approach.